# SQL: float number to hours format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a easy way to format a float number in hours in Ms SQL server 2008?

Examples:

- 1.5   -> 01:30
- 9.8   -> 09:48
- 35.25 -> 35:15

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

I like this question!

```
DECLARE @input float = 1.5;

DECLARE @hour int = FLOOR(@input);
DECLARE @minutes int = (SELECT (@input - FLOOR(@input)) * 60);

SELECT RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), @hour), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2), @minutes), 2);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DATEADD(MINUTE, 1.5*60, ''), 108), 1, 5)
```

This works by:

- starting from the "zero" date
- adding 1.5 x 60 minutes (i.e. 1.5 hours)
- formatting the result as a time, hh:mm:ss (i.e. format "108")
- trimming off the seconds part

It is necessary to use 1.5 x 60 minutes instead of 1.5 hours as the `DATEADD` function truncates the offset to the nearest integer.  If you want high-resolution offsets, you can use `SECOND` instead, suitable scaled (e.g. hours * 60 * 60).

Comment: This is sexy as hell! Nice answer!

Comment: Won't work when the `float` value is greater than or equal to 24. You'll get the time modulo 24 hours (e.g. if X is 35.0, you'll not get `35:00` but `11:00` (35 modulo 24).

Comment: @Nicholas - I, and I'm assuming @WReach as well, was assuming a validated input. Cheers for making a safer version though.

Comment: Nothing about a span of time says that it must be less than 24 horus. OP's sample data includes a value greater than 24.

Comment: @Nicholas You are correct, my answer does not fulfill the exhibited use cases.  I was incorrectly thinking that the desired result was a time-of-day, not an elapsed time.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Easy, but not exactly...straightforward:

```
declare @hours float 
set     @hours = -9.8

select substring('-  ',2+convert(int,sign(@hours)),1)                                        -- sign
     + right('00' + convert(varchar,                       floor(abs(@hours)))         , 2 ) -- hours component
     + ':'                                                                                   -- delimiter
     + right('00' + convert(varchar,round( 60*(abs(@hours)-floor(abs(@hours))) , 0 ) ) , 2 ) -- minutes
```

Another option that will give the correct result. You might need to tweak it to round minutes and to ensure that both fields are 2 digits wide.

```
declare @hours float 
set     @hours = -9.8

select       convert(varchar, datediff(minute,dateadd(minute,@hours*60,convert(datetime,'')),'') / 60 )
     + ':' + convert(varchar, datediff(minute,dateadd(minute,@hours*60,convert(datetime,'')),'') % 60 )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH m AS
  SELECT Minutes = CAST(@hours * 60 AS int)
)
SELECT CAST(Minutes / 60 AS varchar) + ':' + RIGHT(100 + Minutes % 60, 2)
FROM m
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select dateadd(MINUTE, cast((8.18 % 1) * 60 as int), dateadd(hour, cast(8.18 as int), convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 10)))
```